# performing mysql transactions with master and slave setup?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, transactions

how do you deal with transactions when you have master and slave db setup? typically i do all the reads from slaves and writes from master but when performing transactions, it seems i need to do reads from master (the one which is performing the transactions) and so i can't have all my transactions all in one place ...

im also using zend db multidb so i got a separate db instance for master and slave. whats the best way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in MySQL that would prevent you from using the Master db instance for reads as well as writes.  It won't hurt anything.  For your transaction-based queries, I think you'll have to do so.

Comment: Does mean you end up losing many of the advantages of the master/slave setup, though.

Comment: Not that I can think of.  Which advantages would you lose?  Doing this will put a little more load on your Master server, yes, but reads are generally a lot easier on a database than writes.  If you're worried about it, consider upgrading the hardware of your Master or moving to a multi-tiered replication setup where the transactions are on the true Master, and you've got another server performing double-duty shuffling writes from the true Master to your other Slaves.  This is described [here in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-performance.html)

Comment: In my prior comment, I was assuming a small ratio of transactional queries to non-transactional queries.  Sorry for not thinking enough before typing.  If you have a large number, then yes, you'd lose a lot of the advantage of replication.  But I don't know how you'd do transactional queries across multiple databases on different machines.  Can your transactional queries be rewritten so they don't need to be transactional?  Can you pull data from a slave server and put the needed bits into your transactional queries on the Master so you involve fewer tables in those queries?